# Ficus Starlight Leaves "Burn/Burn"

Tags: leaves, ficus

I have Two Ficus starlights in one pot and for some reason one starlight's leaves are getting brown. I water them after 10 days.

Last time i gave them NPK 20-20-20 a month ago

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Older leaves are bound to brown off and fall.  As long as it's only a few leaves and not the younger ones, it's not an issue.

However, one of them looks like it's been chewed by an insect or a small animal.